# How can we do late execution of an html code

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs, web-development-server

I want the part of the html code to only execute when the above form is being submitted.

```
<body>
    <form action="/Recipes" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="recipeName" placeholder="Enter recipe Name" required>
        <button>Find</button>
    </form>
    <!-- The below code should only run once the above form is submitted and should not be executed on the page load -->

    <section class="GPT">
        <h1><%= Name %></h1>

        <% Instructions.forEach(function(instruction) { %>
            <ul><%= instruction %></ul>
        <% }); %>    

        <a href="/"><button>Home</button></a>
    </section>

</body>
```

Following are the technologies that I'm using:

- NodeJS
- EJS
- JavaScript

I tried using functions in JavaScript that should only be called after the submission of the form.

Comment: You need to serve the same page twice, first empty and then with the value of your input passed to the `<input value=""/>` element and the results (if any) in your `GPT` class, any other method **that i'm aware of** would require front-end tech and an API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an additional variable called submitted and set it to `false` on the page load.

```
app.get('/Recipes', (req, res) => {
    // Render the EJS template with submitted set to false (initial page load)
    res.render('recipe', { submitted: false });
});
```

and set the submitted variable to true whenever the name of the recipe is entered and the form is submitted.

```
app.post('/Recipes', (req, res) => {

    // Set submitted to true to render the specific code
    res.render('recipe', { submitted: true, Name: 'Recipe Name', Instructions: ['Step 1', 'Step 2'] });
});
```

here's the full code how I achieved it -

**EJS template file:**

```
<body>
    <form action="/Recipes" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="recipeName" placeholder="Enter recipe Name" required>
        <button>Find</button>
    </form>

    <% if (submitted) { %>
        <!-- The below code will only run if the form is submitted -->
        <section class="GPT">
            <h1><%= Name %></h1>

            <% Instructions.forEach(function(instruction) { %>
                <ul><%= instruction %></ul>
            <% }); %>

            <a href="/"><button>Home</button></a>
        </section>
    <% } %>
</body>
```

**Server End Code (NodeJS)**

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/Recipes', (req, res) => {
    // Render the EJS template with submitted set to false (initial page load)
    res.render('recipe', { submitted: false });
});

app.post('/Recipes', (req, res) => {
    // Process the form submission here

    // Set submitted to true to render the specific code
    res.render('recipe', { submitted: true, Name: 'Recipe Name', Instructions: ['Step 1', 'Step 2'] });
});
```